# error while confirming production order (CO15)

Tags: sap-erp

Getting a warning message while confirming production order using transaction code `CO15` in SAP ERP which is not letting us confirm the `order.Msg`:

> According to factory calendar (2015-03-14) posting date is not a working day (check entry)

Tried changing factory calendar still its not working.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this message is only a warning and if I understand above you say its a warning so you can just press enter to continue. You can also change the posting date on the lower part of the screen to a date that could be in your factory calendar
Later...